# .NET DB2 OLEDB pre-requisites

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I have written a Windows Forms application in C#, .NET framework 2.0, that uses `System.Data.OleDb` to talk to an SQL Server 2000 database, which is working fine. I now need to enhance the application to talk to an [DB2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2) database on [AS/400](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_i). Is this just a matter of configuring the connection string, or do I need additional driver software (where from) and/or references in my project?

I would like to still use OLEDB, but with DB2.

Edit: I downloaded the [Microsoft OLE DB Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ceb4346f-657f-4d28-83f5-aae0c5c83d52) but was unable to install it onto my desktop development PC because I do not have SQL Server installed. This provider seems to be only for integrating SQL Server with DB2, whereas I want to integrate a Windows Forms application with DB2. Is there a different download location for an OLE DB provider that does not require SQL Server, which I can use from a Windows desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will can use Microsoft's [OLEDB for DB2 provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178027.aspx) for this. Also the connection string will change.

Like:

> Provider=DB2OLEDB;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Network Address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=MyCtlg;Package Collection=MyPkgCol;Default Schema=Schema;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Or you can use IBM's own [IBM OLE DB Provider for DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.ms.doc/doc/c0006745.htm) that works without SQL Server.

You should look at *[Connection strings for IBM DB2](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2)* for all other providers and their configuration.

Comment: Is there a download link for that provider? Also please see my edit.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro I'm still not able to download IBM's provider... Is there a download link on the page you suggested?

Comment: You can get the latest Microsoft provider from [Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992)