# Asp.net C# DB2 connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, db2

I am using MVC method and trying to connect to DB2. I have successfully got my connection string using Mysql but when I am going to connect to DB2 I am having this error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in IBM.Data.DB2.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in IBM.Data.DB2.dll but was not handled in user code
Invalid argument
```

The error appears on my connection string code:

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb2"].ConnectionString;
using (DB2Connection con = new DB2Connection(constr))
```

and here is my connection string setup from my web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="ConnStringDb2" connectionString="DATABASE=DB;HOSTNAME=Myhost;PORT=50000;UID=user;PWD=pass;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I already installed the following:

```
IBM data client
IBM database add-ins
```

Is there any items that I am missing or need to add to my connection string or is the format for my connection is invalid. Any suggestion and comments. TIA.

Comment: Are you using OLE DB or DB2 Connector provider? The connection string specified may be different for both cases.

Comment: it's DB2 Connector, check my updated error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [DB2 connection string list](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/), `HOSTNAME` and `PORT` configuration is used for OLE DB provider. For .NET Framework Data Provider usage, you should try one of these configurations below:

```
<!-- using hostname -->
<add name="ConnStringDb2" connectionString="SERVER=Myhost:50000;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=pass;" />

<!-- using server's IP address -->
<add name="ConnStringDb2" connectionString="SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=pass;" />
```

If you currently use OLE DB provider, it is necessary to set DB2 provider name and protocol you're using to connect:

```
<add name="ConnStringDb2" connectionString="PROVIDER=IBMDADB2;DATABASE=DB;HOSTNAME=Myhost;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=user;PWD=pass;" />
```

Related issue: [How to connect to DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487357/how-to-connect-to-db2)

Comment: Cool it works! I just missed some parameters on my connection string.